# Meu site não aparece nos buscadores do google

Tags: seo

Olá, tem uma pergunta semelhante aqui, porém não tem uma resposta válida e acredito que o motivo do site dele não aparecer no rank talvez pode ser diferente do meu.

Enfim, o site http://cursodeimersao.com.br/ já está online a alguns meses.

Fiz alguns testes de SEO nele e ele está com SEO regular.
http://www.seomaster.com.br/ferramentas/analise-seo-gratis/592725
https://www.woorank.com/pt/www/cursodeimersao.com.br

O problema não é o SEO, o problema é que não acho ele no rank do google. (nem  na 20º página e nem em nenhuma).

Porém no bing está logo no topo da pesquisa.

http://www.bing.com/search?q=curso+de+imers%C3%A3o&go=Enviar&qs=n&form=QBLH&pq=curso+de+imers%C3%A3o&sc=8-14&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=e33d41efd45d4003989c6e98baefd59a

Como eu faço para este site aparecer no rank do google? Possuo outros sites, mas este é o único que não aparece.

Comment: No Google com certeza ele está, basta procurar por [site:cursodeimersao.com.br](https://www.google.com.br/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=j5NLVdWjFeeU8Qeb34H4Dw&gws_rd=ssl#q=site:cursodeimersao.com.br). Agora, se ele não está na posição ou página que você esperava, talvez seja questão mesmo de melhorar ele de tal forma que o *rankeamento* seja melhorado, até mesmo o tempo de vida dele, que pelo *whois* me parece que tem pouco mais de 3 meses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tente adicionar a URL junto ao Google manualmente.

- [Google Add URL](https://www.google.com.br/intl/pt-BR/add_url.html)
- [Google Webmaster Add URL](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url?pli=1)

Neste segundo link você deve logar com sua conta Google.

Comment: O primeiro link está quebrado (404).

Comment: @MarcusVinicius, se você estiver logado com seu gmail,você conseguirá acessar. Ou senão, acesse: https://www.google.com/webmasters/ e crie seu cadastro no webmaster tools para adicionar URL

Answer (score 2):

O Google, via de regra, "segura" o ranking dos novos sites, impedindo eles de aparecer nos resultados de busca. Pelo menos por algum tempo. Ou seja, mesmo que você trabalhe seu SEO e obtenha um alto ranqueamento em pouco tempo, seu site não consegue aproveitar todo seu ranqueamento durante um tempo. A liberação é gradual.
O Google faz isso no intuito de preservar a relevância de seus resultados, e combater práticas "SEO black hat".

Segue abaixo uma estimativa de quanto o Google "segura" seu ranqueamento de acordo com o tempo de vida do site:

1. Até 1 mês: segura 100% do ranqueamento
2. Até 2 meses: segura 75% do ranqueamento
3. Até 6 meses: segura 50% do ranqueamento
4. Até 1 ano: segura 25% do ranqueamento
5. Até 2 anos: segura 10% do ranqueamento
6. Até 3 anos: segura 5% do ranqueamento
7. Até 4 ano: segura 0% do ranqueamento

Esses números são apenas estimados, mas dão uma idéia do comportamento do seu site nos resultados de busca.

Comment: Muito interessante, você tem alguma fonte sobre o assunto?

Comment: é fácil de achar no google, mas eu indicaria o livro Outsmarting Google: SEO Secrets to Winning New Business (Que Biz-Tech), ele é bem completo sobre o assunto

Comment: Tem referências desses dados?

Comment: Conforme livro citado acima