# O domínio do site hospedado não aparece no buscador do Google

Tags: google, seo

Não posso mostrar o *site* por motivos éticos.

O portal não aparece em nenhuma página do Google, nem quando eu digito o URL no buscador. O *site* só aparece quando eu digito o URL no *browser*. Eu verifiquei as *meta tags* no código fonte e pude perceber que as mesmas estão incompletas. O diagnóstico do SEOquake deu mais para negativo. Não sei se isto é motivo para não aparecer em nenhum lugar do buscador, não sei se era para aparecer em pelo menos na 5º página.

Comment: O site tem o arquivo `robots.txt` na pasta publica? Se sim, veja se ele está bloqueando o Googlebot ou qualquer `user-agent`

Comment: Então vai ser legal, você precisa que ele apareça no Google mas não pode mostra por motivos éticos. Boa sorte! Um site não entra no buscador por conta própria, tem que cadastrar nele ou ter links para ele, além de obviamente precisa estar disponível para todos, o que é o oposto do que você quer. Eu já vi site levar meses para entrar mesmo tendo feito isto. Algumas coisa podem ajudar como incluir um *sitemap* nos padrões que eles determinam, mas não vai influenciar no tempo de entrada. Não ter problemas dentro das regras deles também ajuda.

Comment: https://support.google.com/sites/answer/100283?hl=en https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6259634?hl=en https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34444?hl=en Fora isto, pode ser que o conteúdo é ruim, por uma série de razões que não podemos ajudar porque não podemos ver, e não liste facilmente o site. Não existe milagre.

Answer (score 0):

Existem inúmeras razões pra isso acontecer, tal como o @KaduAmaral disse, verifica se o robots.txt não está a bloquear nada.

Depois adiciona o site neste link, https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url, isto vai basicamente informar o Google de que o site existe e para o bot deles lá ir dar uma vista de olhos.

Também recomendo a usares a esta ferramenta para webmasters do Google https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home, isto vai-te ajudar a perceber melhor o que se está a passar, pois vai-te dar um diagnóstico completo do site.

Por último, lê o manual da Google para SEO (se é que ainda não o fizeste), https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/en//webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf, e vás programando consoante as dicas que eles dão ;)

Answer (score 0):

O Google, via de regra, "segura" o ranking dos novos sites, impedindo eles de aparecer nos resultados de busca. Pelo menos por algum tempo.

[Veja aqui uma resposta que pode te ajudar.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/85878/32425)